# not able to get results to paginate

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Good day all, I have been beating my head against this, unless I have missed how it is supposed to work then I had better get back to the drawing board.  I went up and got a script working to search my database and the 50,000 records that I have.  I searched the internet for everything there is to know and where to get pagination or how it will work but all I found was coding for it.  Since I am a relative newbie on mysql and PHP, I am at a loss.

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>GT Entertainment Song Database</title>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style>
BODY, TD {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="search.php">
<label>Date Added</label>
<select name="clock">
<option value="">--</option>

<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY clock ORDER BY clock     LIMIT 1,40";
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not     execute SQL query" '.$sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row["clock"]."'".    ($row["clock"]==$_REQUEST["clock"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["clock"]."</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
<label>Title or Artist:</label>
<input type="text" name="string" id="string" value="<?php echo     stripcslashes($_REQUEST["string"]); ?>" />
<label>Disk</label>
<select name="Disk">
<option value="">--</option>

<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY Disk ORDER BY Disk     LIMIT 1,40";
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not     execute SQL query" '.$sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row["Disk"]."'".($row["Disk"]==$_REQUEST["Disk"]     ? " selected" : "").">".$row["Disk"]."</option>";
        }
?><BR>
</select><BR>
<label>Duet</label>
<select name="Duet">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY Duet ORDER BY Duet     LIMIT 1,40";
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not     execute SQL query" '.$sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row["Duet"]."'".($row["Duet"]==$_REQUEST["Duet"]     ? " selected" : "").">".$row["Duet"]."</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
<label>Comment</label>
<select name="Comment">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY Comment ORDER BY     Comment LIMIT 1,40";
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not     execute SQL query" '.$sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row["Comment"]."'".    ($row["Comment"]==$_REQUEST["Comment"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["Comment"]."</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" />
  </label>
  <a href="search.php">
  reset</a>
</form>
<br /><br />
<table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
      <tr>
    <td width="90" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Date Added</strong></td>
    <td width="95" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Track</strong></td>
    <td width="159" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Artist</strong></td>
    <td width="191" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Disk</strong></td>
    <td width="113" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Duet</strong></td>
    <td width="113" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Comment</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?php

// Start query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE 1=1 ";

if ($_REQUEST["string"]!='') {
        $sql .= " AND (Track LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%'     OR Artist LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')";
}
if ($_REQUEST["Disk"]!='') {
        $sql .= " AND Disk='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["Disk"])."'"; 
}

if ($_REQUEST["Comment"]!='') {
        $sql .= " AND Comment='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["Comment"])."'";
}
if ($_REQUEST["clock"]!='') {
        $sql .= " AND clock='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["clock"])."'";
}
if ($_REQUEST["Duet"]!='') {
        $sql .= " AND Duet='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["Duet"])."'";
}
$sql .= " LIMIT 40";

$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL     query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {

?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["clock"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Track"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Artist"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Disk"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Duet"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Comment"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
        }
} else {
?>
<tr><td colspan="6">No results found.</td>
<?php  
}
?>
```

Now I have looked at this following code and I cannot seem to get it to incorporate into my currently working script so that the results can be split into separate pages if the amount of results are above my limit I have set.

I found this information [Here](http://www.phpjabbers.com/php--mysql-select-data-and-split-on-pages-php25.html)

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT $start_from, 20"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql,$connection); 
?> 
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Phone</td></tr>
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
?> 
            <tr>
            <td><? echo $row["Name"]; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $row["PhoneNumber"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php 
}; 
?> 
</table>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM students"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql,$connection); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 20); 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
?>
```

Everytime that I try to make it work or place the code where it should fit, I keep getting errors and I am at a loss.

Below is where I have gotten to in my attempt in making pagination work for me, I am not sure if I am going in the right direction

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." ORDER BY clock ASC LIMIT     $start_from, 20";
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not     execute SQL query" '.$sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row["clock"]."'".    ($row["clock"]==$_REQUEST["clock"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["clock"]."</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
<label>Title or Artist:</label>
<input type="text" name="string" id="string" value="<?php echo     stripcslashes($_REQUEST["string"]); ?>" />
<label>Disk</label>
<select name="Disk">
<option value="">--</option>

<?php
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." ORDER BY Disk ASC LIMIT     $start_from, 20";
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not     execute SQL query" '.$sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row["Disk"]."'".($row["Disk"]==$_REQUEST["Disk"]     ? " selected" : "").">".$row["Disk"]."</option>";
        }
?><BR>
</select><BR>
<label>Duet</label>
<select name="Duet">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." ORDER BY Duet ASC LIMIT     $start_from, 20";
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not     execute SQL query" '.$sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row["Duet"]."'".($row["Duet"]==$_REQUEST["Duet"]     ? " selected" : "").">".$row["Duet"]."</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
<label>Comment</label>
<select name="Comment">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." ORDER BY Comment ASC LIMIT     $start_from, 20";
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not     execute SQL query" '.$sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row["Comment"]."'".    ($row["Comment"]==$_REQUEST["Comment"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["Comment"]."</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" />
  </label>
  <a href="search.php">
  reset</a>
</form>
<br /><br />
<table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
    <td width="90" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Date Added</strong></td>
    <td width="95" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Track</strong></td>
    <td width="159" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Artist</strong></td>
    <td width="191" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Disk</strong></td>
    <td width="113" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Duet</strong></td>
    <td width="113" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Comment</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?php

// Start query
$sql = "SELECT COUNT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"].";

if ($_REQUEST["string"]!='') {
        $sql .= " AND (Track LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%'     OR Artist LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')";
}
if ($_REQUEST["Disk"]!='') {
        $sql .= " AND Disk='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["Disk"])."'"; 
}

if ($_REQUEST["Comment"]!='') {
        $sql .= " AND Comment='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["Comment"])."'";
}
if ($_REQUEST["clock"]!='') {
        $sql .= " AND clock='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["clock"])."'";
}
if ($_REQUEST["Duet"]!='') {
        $sql .= " AND Duet='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["Duet"])."'";
}

$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL     query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 20); 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='search.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["clock"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Track"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Artist"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Disk"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Duet"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Comment"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
        }
} else {
?>
<tr><td colspan="6">No results found.</td>
<?php  
}
?>

</table>
```

Any assistance is always appreciated
Thank you all in advance

Comment: What are the errors you're getting specifically and under which circumstances?

Comment: the error I was getting is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING. it will not even load the search engine the way it is now.

Comment: It means there's an error with code itself, not necessarily the logic. Go to the line it mentions and try to fix the problem there.

Comment: I have included the code for the line that is failing. `if ($_REQUEST["string"]!='') {`

Comment: I have added more information to show where I may be failing in my coding